# Play the Video/Audio which is getting from the server

Tags: blackberry

Is there any solution of this below one?

I have the Video/audio URLs

My Requirement is:

> Is it possible to get the video/audio from the server and at the same time I have to open the player to play it(Like showing the Live-video directly in browser Field).

Means

> Getting streaming into a buffer in back-end and at the same time I want to show it in the player.

If above is possible

> I want to save that particular video/audio streaming data in to one file.

Comment: some body goes around my blog and give the down Voted 2 or 3 questions at a time..........! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  [blackberry KB link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Streaming-media-Start-to-finish/ta-p/488255) explains about streaming video from server. It may help you.

Comment: Thanks for response. I already tried that zip file its not working.